# C# Entiity Framework. Exception: The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, файлы, entity-framework

Суть проблемы: мне нужно сохранить изменения в базе. После чего сравнить хешсумму базы с предыдущей и восстановить базу из бекапа, если они не совпадают (звучит странно, но такая уж задача)

```
        Model.GameBaseContext.getInsance().SaveChanges();
        File.WriteAllBytes(Paths.GameBasePath, File.ReadAllBytes(Paths.BackUP));
```

На второй строчке вылетает ошибка.
Если проверить открыта ли база, после сохранения изменений

```
var test = Model.GameBaseContext.getInsance().Database.Connection.State;
```

то test всегда == closed;

Если написать Thread.Sleep(1000); то это помогает, но не всегда, иногда секунды ему не хватает, и все равно вылетает ошибка.

Вызов GC тоже ничего не дает (да я отчаялся и попробовал даже это)

Собственно вопрос, что вообще может блокировать файл и как его освободить?

Comment: Во-первых зачем вы читаете весь файл в оперативку и после записываете? `File.Copy()` не решает ваши проблемы? _что вообще может блокировать файл_ - как например то, что вы работаете с этой базой?

Comment: я немного упростил код, мне в любом случае надо считать байты из файла базы данных, чтобы вычислить ее хэш сумму.

Сам файл не большой, меньше мегабайта.

Comment: а что будет, когда база вырастет? В любом случае вы можете сделать без полной загрузки файла в оперативу, например [так](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10520086/5598926)

Comment: Ничего больше файл блокировать не может. Никакой асинхронной работы с базой, взаимодействие только через Model.GameBaseContext этот контекст.

Comment: База не может вырасти по самой логике программы. Но согласен, наверное лучше переделать. Но это все равно никак не решает проблему, того что система думает что файл открыт.

Comment: а что у вас в этой базе хранится-то? Если она вырасти не может - может тогда использование баз данных избыточно?

Comment: суть в том, что программа - обучающий комплекс. В этом месте студенту надо будет найти бекап и удалить его, чтобы система не могла восстановить состояние базы до изменения.

Comment: Перед вызовом `GC` выполняется `Dispose`?
`var instance = Model.GameBaseContext.getInsance();
instance.SaveChanges();
instance.Dispose();
GC.Collect();`

Comment: Дополнение: `Connection.State` с состоянием `Closed` говорит о том, что можно безопасно закрыть соединение. Но соединение все еще нужно закрыть: `instance.Dispose()`.